# Framework not being overwritten in WP Child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have  a theme, which seems to have a framework folder, the coding isnt great so I have had to make some changes, and have created a child theme to do this. This works fine, except for 1 file which when I drop into my child theme it doesnt overide the parent. Being new to WP im a bit flumoxed about this.

So these (and other) file works and overwrites the parent
wp-content/themes/homes-child/functions.php
wp-content/themes/homes-child/property-details/property-contents.php

However this one, if I make changes to the live file, they work, if I make them to the child, no change. I see it part of a framework, and have tried dropping in the whole framework folder, but no use.
wp-content/themes/homes-child/framework/include/property-post-type.php

is there a way to debug why WP is not picking up this child theme file?

Answer (score 0):

At a really blind guess, I am assuming that WP isn't executing property-post-type.php in your child theme folder because it is called from functions.php, which, unlike stylesheets / templates, in a child theme, does not override its parent functionality, it adds to it.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php

Usually when developing child themes, you'll need to setup filters and action to override this behavior. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference